# How to access grails plugins directory in cloudbees from jenkins

Tags: grails, jenkins, cloudbees

I would like to execute a pre-build (grails) script from jenkins to replace a file in the plugins directory with a file in my SCM.

```
#!/bin/bash
PLUGINS_ORIG_DIR="plugins"
PLUGINS_DEST_DIR="/home/<my_user_name>/.grails/2.1.1/projects/judo/plugins"
cp -r $PLUGINS_ORIG_DIR/lang-selector-0.3/* $PLUGINS_DEST_DIR
```

But the script fails because the $PLUGINS_DEST_DIR cannot be found. Which should be the path or which is the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

I have also tried to create an pre-war event, but it does not work either:

```
/**
 * Copy modified resources to plugins directory, before packing the WAR
 */
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
    def buildSettings = BuildSettingsHolder.getSettings() 

    def projectPluginsDir = buildSettings.getProperty("projectPluginsDir")
    def baseDir = buildSettings.getProperty("baseDir")

    ant.copy(todir:"${projectPluginsDir}/lang-selector-0.3", overwrite:true) {
        fileset(dir:"${basedir}/plugins/lang-selector-0.3", includes:"**")
    }

    ant.copy(todir:"${projectPluginsDir}/jquery-datatables-1.7.5", overwrite:true) {
        fileset(dir:"${basedir}/plugins/jquery-datatables-1.7.5", includes:"**")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by copying files to ${stagingDir}, instead of ${projectPluginsDir}

Answer (score 0):

as  did you set your cloudbees account name ?
then you're wrong, should use /home/jenkins or just $HOME, as builds run on general purpose slaves as "jenkins" user

Comment: Now, the error is "cp: cannot create directory `/home/jenkins/.grails/2.1.1/projects/judo/plugins': No such file or directory"